# Increase a cell value by 1 if contains a number or letter

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a VBA setup to increase the number of the cell by 1 when i click a button

```
Sub IncreaseCellValue()
'Add 1 to the existing cell value
Range("A1").Value = Range("A1") + 1
End Sub
```

This has been working fine for my invoices to save and add next number , but now i'm creating invoices that start with a letter sometimes. So for example , the cell could be 5766662  or W5766662. The above works for numbers only, so i tried the following to get it working without an error for letters/numbers , but its not working

```
Sub IncreaseCellValue()
    Dim value As Variant

    'Add 1 to the existing cell value

    If IsNumeric(Range("A1").value) Then
       Range("A1").value = Range("A1") + 1
    Else
       value = Split(Range("A1").value, " ")
       Range("A1").value = value(0) & " " & (CInt(value(1)) + 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

The above does work in the cell is W 5766662   , if a space is between the letter and number it works , but i need it to work for W5766662 or 5766662

Comment: Is it always 1 character, the first that is not a number?

Comment: or can we assume that the number is always 7 digits?

Comment: yes , always 1 letter in front of the numbers OR no letter at all.   H1111 or 1111

Comment: number of digits varies

Comment: The just do: `Range("A1").value = left(Range("A1").value,1) & (CLng(mid(Range("A1").value,2)) + 1)`

Comment: thank you , that worked perfectly

Comment: Will you have to increment 5999999 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simple if you continue to use IsNumeric and Trim to get the proper value.

Adding an error trap just in case, it would now look like:

```
Sub IncreaseCellValue()
    Dim value As Variant

    'Add 1 to the existing cell value

    If IsNumeric(Range("A1").value) Then
        Range("A1").value = Range("A1") + 1
    Else
        ' Discard first character and trim spaces
        value = Trim(Mid(Range("A1").value, 2)) + 1
        If IsNumeric(value) Then
            Range("A1").value = value
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid Cell Value: " & Range("A1").value
        End If
        
    End If
End Sub
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Write formulas in VBA，this is for your reference only.

```
Sub IncreaseCellValue()
Range("Z1").Formula = "=TEXT(LEFT(A1),)&-LOOKUP(,-RIGHT(A1,ROW($1:$15)))+1"
[A1] = [Z1].Value: [Z1].Delete
End Sub
```